# Ошибка "Android SDK not found", хотя переменная ANDROID_HOME установлена

Tags: android, android-sdk, phonegap

Я установила переменные среды JAVA_HOME и ANDROID_HOME:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а также изменила переменную Path, добавив туда `%Android_HOME%\tools;%Android_HOME%\platform-tools`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И всё равно при выполнении команды “`phonegap requirements android`” я получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть ошибка говорит о том, что Android SDK не найдено:

> Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at
>   the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

но при этом поиск gradle происходит в папке ANDROID_HOME:

> Looked here: **D:\Android\sdk**\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper

да и вызов команды с "android ..." из командного окна даёт результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что говорит о том, что переменные связанные с android-sdk, установлены правильно...

В чём причина этой ошибка и как эту ошибку можно исправить?

Comment: Я надеюсь вы перезагрузили ПК после установки переменных среды, ибо это винда.

Comment: @mit, после перезагрузки ПК всё то же самое